# Unable to implement TcpSocketServer in Log4j2

Tags: java, spring-boot, logging, log4j2

I am trying to write logs in a SpringBoot application to a remote server using [SocketAppender](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.0/log4j-core/apidocs/org/apache/logging/log4j/core/appender/SocketAppender.html) in Log4j2. First I run the listener application (which is also a spring boot application) where I have implemented the [TcpSocketServer](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/log4j-2.7/log4j-core/apidocs/org/apache/logging/log4j/core/net/server/TcpSocketServer.html) and then I run my main application. I am getting the the following errors. Main app runs on localhost:8080 and listener app runs on localhost:9600.

Am I doing it the right way? How can I correctly implement this logging? I could not find a proper example online.

> In listener application

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid character found in method name. HTTP method names must be tokens
```

> In main application

```
2019-06-20 17:24:28,091 main ERROR Unable to write to stream 
TCP:localhost:9600 for appender socket-appender: org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.AppenderLoggingException: Error writing to TCP:localhost:9600
2019-06-20 17:24:28,092 main ERROR An exception occurred processing Appender socket-appender org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.AppenderLoggingException: Error writing to TCP:localhost:9600
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe (Write failed)
```

**My Implementation**

> Log4j2 configurations in main app

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="debug">
    <Appenders>
        <Socket name="socket-appender" host="localhost" port="9600">
            <JsonLayout properties="true"/>
        </Socket>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <AsyncLogger  name="socket-appender" level="info">
            <AppenderRef ref="socket-appender"/>
        </AsyncLogger>
        <AsyncRoot level="info">
            <AppenderRef ref="socket-appender"/>
        </AsyncRoot>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

> Log4j2 configurations in listener app

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="debug" name="SocketServer">
    <Appenders>
        <RollingRandomAccessFile name="Rolling-Random-Access-File-Appender"
                                 fileName="logs/rollingrandomaccessfile.log"
                                 filePattern="archive/logs/rollingrandomaccessfile.log.%d{yyyy-MM-dd-hh-mm}.gz">
            <PatternLayout pattern="[%-5level] %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %c{1} - %msg%n"/>
            <Policies>
                <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="1 KB"/>
            </Policies>
            <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="30"/>
        </RollingRandomAccessFile>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <AsyncLogger>
            <AppenderRef ref="Rolling-Random-Access-File-Appender"/>
        </AsyncLogger>
        <AsyncRoot level="info">
            <AppenderRef ref="Rolling-Random-Access-File-Appender"/>
        </AsyncRoot>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

> TcpSocketServer Implementation in listener app

```
package com.springReceiver.receiveFromSocket;

import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.net.server.ObjectInputStreamLogEventBridge;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.net.server.TcpSocketServer;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;

class Receiver {

    void writeLogs(){

        TcpSocketServer<ObjectInputStream> server = null;
        try {
            server = new TcpSocketServer<>(9600,new ObjectInputStreamLogEventBridge());
            server.run();
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in client side try this config:

```
<Socket name="socket" host="xxxxxxxxx" port="1090" connectTimeoutMillis="1000" reconnectionDelayMillis="1000" >
            <SerializedLayout />
</Socket>
```

Comment: Using the SerializedLayout without whitelisting the objects that can be deserialized is a security hole.

Answer (score 0):

First, your TCPServer appears to be using the unmodified code from logging-log4j-tools which has never been released - for a very good reason. That code expects the payload being sent to be a Java serialized LogEvent. But the code is not performing any whitelisting on the objects that can be deserialized, which is a security vulnerability (See https://www.cvedetails.com/cve/CVE-2017-5645/).

Switching to the JSONLayout as your client configuration does is a much better approach, but that means your server will have to convert the JSON back to a LogEvent which also means you will need to include code to be able to reconstruct any objects your are passing or else they will just be treated as Maps.